# Equivalent of FlatList from React Native in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Is there an equivalent of the [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) component from React Native in React? Having built a mobile app in React Native, I'm now converting it to React for a web app. (Have considered using [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web), but have decided against it, mainly because I want to learn React.)

If there isn't an equivalent, I have been thinking about just using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to render all the items via an Item component that I build, also as demonstrated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in the docs and in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react).

Comment: Try using react-native-web, It might save you a lot of time converting your code to web. You can make all your components cross-platform.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no specific component like it is in react-native to do this kind of stuff, so I usually just use `map()` to achieve this kind of things.

But if it is reusable you can surely create a List component for yourself so that you don't write `map()` function each time for the same list.

Kind of like this:

```
function Item(props) {
   return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function MyList(items) {
   return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => <Item key={item.key} value={item} />)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: The benefit of a FlatList would be that it only renders the components that are visible on the screen. Using `map` wouldn't do this

Answer (score 11):

There is a react component called `flatlist-react` (npm install flatlist-react) that you can use to render lists like:

```js
<FlatList list={[1, 2, 3]} renderItem={item => <li>{item}</li>}/>
```

It also handles things like sorting, grouping, filtering and layout styling for you.

Project:

https://github.com/ECorreia45/flatlist-react

Answer (score 8):

The official react site [suggests](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists)  the [react-window](https://react-window.now.sh/) and [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/)

Comment: i tried react-virtualized and really sucks, since required props are: width, height, rowCount, rowheight, wtf they can calculate it if needed, just sucks.

Answer (score 4):

React-Native works by exposing native Andriod and iOS components via JavaScript.

Android and iOS have their respective `ListViews` which are internally called when using `FlatList`.

HTML does not have a list component equivalent to ListViews on iOS and Android.
You could use a library that does this like https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview or use `Array.map` to return `divs` that you want rendered and implement the equivalent scroll logic yourself.

Comment: `recyclerlistview` doesn't work well on dynamic height item, which is useless, because many list view have dynamic height

Answer (score 1):

This project includes a lot of the features for Flat List/List View - but seems to approve upon it, it's for React Native and Web, you can read this article:

https://medium.com/@naqvitalha/recyclerlistview-high-performance-listview-for-react-native-and-web-e368d6f0d7ef

Some interesting points:

> FlatList:
>
> FlatList is amazing and comes with tons of features. It even lets you
>   render separators and comes with a built in customisable view tracker
>   which is something we were interested in.
>
> FlatList is a virtualized listview and it does so by unmounting views
>   that have gone out of viewport. It does help bring down overall memory
>   usage down but there are cons to this approach:
>
> Views on native end get destroyed causing lot of garbage collection.
>   Views need to be recreated now as you scroll up which might be a
>   problem if the scroll is quick.

Project:

https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

Answer (score 1):

I create a component for this

```
export const FlatList = ({
  items,
  RenderItem,
  ListHeaderComponent,
  ListFooterComponent,
  ListEmptyComponent,
}) => {
  // console.log(Render)

  // console.log(items, "items");

  if (Array.isArray(items)) {
    const render = items.map((v, i) => {
      return RenderItem({ data: v, key: i });
    });

    // console.log(render, "render");

    if (render.length) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          {ListHeaderComponent ? ListHeaderComponent() : null}
          {render}
          {ListFooterComponent ? ListFooterComponent() : null}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {ListHeaderComponent ? ListHeaderComponent() : null}
        {ListEmptyComponent ? ListEmptyComponent() : null}
        {ListFooterComponent ? ListFooterComponent() : null}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  if (ListHeaderComponent || ListEmptyComponent || ListEmptyComponent) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {ListHeaderComponent ? ListHeaderComponent() : null}

        {ListEmptyComponent ? ListEmptyComponent() : null}
        {ListFooterComponent ? ListFooterComponent() : null}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

I used it like this

```
            <FlatList items={dataAdmin} RenderItem={RenderAdmins} />
```

You don't have to worry about key, this component handle that automatically. Your RenderItem component should look like this

```
const RenderAdmins = ({ data, key }) => {
  const org = data.organization;
  if (org) {
    return (
      <StyledTableRow key={key}>
        <StyledTableCell align="center">{org.name}</StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="center">{data.email}</StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="center">{org.phone}</StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="center">{data.phone}</StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="center">
          {data.first_name + " " + data.last_name}
        </StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="center">{org.address}</StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="center">Eti Osa</StyledTableCell>
      </StyledTableRow>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

Your items should be an array.