# React js does not update a JSX array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been learning React for 2 weeks and right now I'm trying to figure out how Lifting State Up works. In this code I'm trying to make a simple counter, you click the decrement or increment button and I update the state with this function called handleButtons. I'm handling my state object in my main file 'App.js' because this way I can use as many 'Counter' components as I want and they share the same state so I can update all Counters with a single button. I used the 'componentWillMount' function to create the 'Counter' components array and show it in my render function. The problem is when I click on one of these buttons nothing happens. The state is updated (I can see it on the console) but the counter components still showing '0' on the webpage.

This is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Counter} from './components/Counter';


class App extends React.Component{

  state = {
    count: 0
  }

  counters = []

  handleButtons = (event) => {
    if(event.target.name === 'increment'){
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
      }) 
    }else if(event.target.name === 'decrement'){
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count - 1
      })
    }
    console.log(this.state.count)
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    for(let i = 0; i< 10;i++){
      this.counters.push(<div key = {i}><Counter count = {this.state.count}/><br/></div>)
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className = 'App'>
        {this.counters}
        <button className = 'Button' name = 'increment' onClick = {this.handleButtons}>Increment</button><br/><br/>
        <button className = 'Button' name = 'decrement' onClick = {this.handleButtons}>Decrement</button>

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

and this is my Counter.js file

```
import React from 'react';

export class Counter extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = 'App'>
                {this.props.count}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I expected the components to increment their values and they did but it doesn't refresh on the browser

Comment: ComponentWillMount runs the code before the app mounted i.e (before render function calls) . It is not suggested by react as it is unsafe . Here is working url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p9i5nt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some answers already however i want to elaborate the problem as well and add on top of other answers as you are starting with React. Understanding the problem is the first and most important step in learning:

**Problem:**
You were using lifecycle method `componentWillMount` which runs at the time of mount which is at start and generates the array of counters using the loop. Now your list of counters has a state dependency which is resolved within the lifecycle method only once with the initial value `0`. Why? `componentWillMount` is designed to be run only once so when your state updates, it doesn't affect anything in `componentWillMount` or your `Counter` list inputs. This is why, whatever needs to get rendered should be in the render function or called from render function and not linked with lifecycle methods.

**Solution:**
You don't need to generate it in `componentWillMount`. It can simply be handled in the `render` method and since you will be defining the `state` dependency in the render method, React will make sure that whenever state is updated, your list of Counters get updated.

**Enough talk, show me the code:**
Code snippet below would be your new render function and you can safely delete the `componentWillMount`, although you can generate list in multiple styles but i am taking your lead here.

```
render() {
    let counterList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      counterList.push(
        <div key={i}>
          <Counter count={this.state.count} />
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {counterList}
        <button
          className="Button"
          name="increment"
          onClick={this.handleButtons}
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button
          className="Button"
          name="decrement"
          onClick={this.handleButtons}
        >
          Decrement
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[See the working code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ellis-b2s26).

Separately, React has declared `componentWillMount` as unsafe, all the more reasons to not use it and if you think you really need it, use the constructor.

Consult [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) for more.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Nice answer; but put the essential parts of your code in the answer itself, not as a hyperlink; that can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are so many things wrong on this code. Let start simple, React component import:

```
componentWillMount(){
    for(let i = 0; i< 10;i++){
      this.counters.push(<div key = {i}><Counter count = {this.state.count}/><br/></div>)
    }
  }
```

This is wrong, you don't use the components like this (You can, but it is not how it has to be used), the component is used inside the render function as this:

```
render(){
 return(
  <div className = 'App'>
    <Counter count={this.state.count} /> //this line right here is the important
    <button className = 'Button' name = 'increment' onClick = {this.handleButtons}>Increment</button><br/><br/>
    <button className = 'Button' name = 'decrement' onClick = {this.handleButtons}>Decrement</button>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Notice that we removed that strange array you had, and we used the component imported Counter, notice too, that we add an atribute (prop in jsx) that is equal to the counter in this state.

Everytime you mutate (change, update) the state, the render function is executed and the elements re-rendered, so, now, everytime you update the state with setState() the counter will be rendered with the new value.

My advice then, **remove the entire componentWillMount()** as now its useless and also remove the counters = [] property of the parent class.

Also note that ComponentWillMount() only when the component is created, if you wanted to do it this way, you had to use **ComponentDidUpdate()** that its executed everytime you mutate the state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what happens if I want to use more Counter components?.  For example, right now I'd like to render 10 Counter components but maybe in the future, I'll like to render 20. So I need something where I specify the number of Counter of components I want to render. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @RobertoDieguez Then do it as you where doing, but move the entire componentWillMount to componentDidUpdate. ComponentDidUpdate runs everytime you mutate/update the state, componentWillMount only once when the component is created.

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillMount` is not right in your case.
You can use `arrow` function to show.

```
// prepare counters items to render
  renderCounters = () => {
    const { count } = this.state;
    let counters = [];
    for(let i = 0; i< 10;i++){
      counters.push(<div key = {i}><Counter count={count}/></div>);
    }
    return counters;
  }
...
// render function
  render(){
    return(
      <div className = 'App'>
        {this.renderCounters()}
        <button className = 'Button' name = 'increment' onClick = {this.handleButtons}>Increment</button><br/><br/>
        <button className = 'Button' name = 'decrement' onClick = {this.handleButtons}>Decrement</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

When state value is changed somehow, the component will be rerendered automatically. 
This means `render` function is called.
You don't need to worry about preparing your components to show in `render` function. But you only should not call `setState` in `render` function.

If you have an array to render, you can use `map` function in `arrow` function or `render` function directly.

Let's imagine that you have an array to show as 'myCounters',

```
// render function

  render(){
    const { myCounters } = this.state;
    return(
      <div className = 'App'>
        {myCounters.map((item, index) => 
             <div key = {index}>
                 <Counter count={item.count}/>
             </div>)
        }
        <button className = 'Button' name = 'increment' onClick = {this.handleButtons}>Increment</button><br/><br/>
        <button className = 'Button' name = 'decrement' onClick = {this.handleButtons}>Decrement</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like this question as you have actually stumbled onto an edge case that I didn't think about until now.

Basically, what's going on is, because you are adding the components in a list that's not in the state in your componentWillMount function. These "Counter" components actually won't be updated and become removed from the component lifecycle.

All you have to do, it make sure these counters are added to the lifecycle. You do this by defining a list and mapping it in your render function. See here:
[Rendering an array.map() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react)

Hope that helps!