# Render Data in Cloud Firestore with a ReactJS Hook

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How can I render data retrieved from Cloud Firestore using ReactJS native functional component?

I want to do something like this:

```js
    const result=[]

    db.collection("collection").where("parameter", "==", "value")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            result.push(doc.data());
        });

    export default function foo(){
     return(
       <View>
        {result.map((item) =>
          <CustomComponent data=item />
        )}
       </View>
     )
    }
```

Obviously the code does not work because the rendering happens before the promise resolving. I have read a lot on the internet. A possible solution is to update the state in the `ComponentDidMount`, in which the request to db happens.

So my question is, how can I do it with a functional component? Is this the only and best solution? The data which I want to retrieve from Firestore and I want to display not change so fast.

Answer (score 0):

Hers is a code snippet hope it works for you....

```
const useData = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const getData = () => {
    const data = [];
    db.collection('collection')
      .where('parameter', '==', 'value')
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          data.push(doc.data());
        });
        setList(data);
      });
  };

  return [loading, list, getData];
};

export default function App() {
  const [loading, list, getData] = useData();

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        {
          // renderList
        }
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are trying to render an array of data. I suggest taking a look at this good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react). I have added a few examples of ReactJS map that you might find helpful:

```js
render() {
    return (<div>
    {this.state.people.map((person, index) => (
        <p key={index}>Hello, {person.name} from {person.country}!</p>
    ))}
    </div>);
}
```

```js
this.state.data.map(function(item, i){
  console.log('test');
  return <li key={i}>Test</li>
})
```

You might find these tutorials and userguides helpful:

- [Getting started with Cloud Firestore and React Native](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage).
- [Create React Native Firebase CRUD App with Firestore](https://www.positronx.io/create-react-native-firebase-crud-app-with-firestore/).