# Edit a Cloud Firestore record from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to edit the recipes record from a ReactJS app on the Cloud Firestore database. I am not sure how to access all the parameters of the update useState hook, below is the code:

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'

    function Recipes(props) {
    const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false)
    
    const[update,setUpdate] = useState({
      id:null,
      recipeName: '',
      ingredients:[],
       desc:''
    });
    
    const [toUpdateId, setToUpdateId] = useState('')
    
        function showEdit(){
          setEdit(true);
          openUpdateDialog(props.recipeName)
        }
    
        const openUpdateDialog = (newRecipe) => {
          setEdit(true);
          setToUpdateId(newRecipe.id);
          setUpdate({
            id:newRecipe.id,
                recipeName: newRecipe.title,
                ingredients:newRecipe.ingredients,
                 desc:newRecipe.desc
      });
    }
    
        function closeModal(){
          if(edit){
            setEdit(false)
          }
        }
    
        const editRecipe = () => {
          db.collection('recipes').doc(toUpdateId).update({
              title: update,
               ingredients:update,
                // desc:update.desc
    
          });
          setEdit(false);
      }
    
      const handleClose = () => {
        setEdit(false)
      }
    
      return (
        <Accordion>
       
          <Card>
            <Card.Title>{props.newRecipe.title}</Card.Title>
         
            <Card.Body>
              <ol>
             
                {props.newRecipe.ingredients.split(',').map((item)=> {
                return (
        <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                )
                })}
              </ol>
              <Card.Text>
          {props.newRecipe.desc}
            </Card.Text>
            
              <ButtonToolbar>
                <Button variant="danger" onClick={event => db.collection('recipes').doc(props.newRecipe.id).delete()}>Delete</Button>
                
                <Button variant="info" onClick={() => {openUpdateDialog(props.newRecipe)}}>Edit</Button>
              </ButtonToolbar>
           
            </Card.Body>
        
          </Card>
       <Modal show={edit} onHide={closeModal}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Edit Recipe</Modal.Title>
        <Modal.Body>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel>Recipe Name:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl type="text"
            value={update.recipeName}
            name="recipeName"
            placeholder="Enter Recipe Name"
            onChange={e=>setUpdate(e.target.value)}
            >
            </FormControl>
          </FormGroup>
    
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel>Recipe Ingredients:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl type="textarea"
            value={update.ingredients}
            name="ingredients"
            placeholder="Enter Recipe Ingredients separated by commas"
            onChange={e=>setUpdate(e.target.value)}
            >
            </FormControl>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel>Recipe Description:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl type="textarea"
            value={update.desc}
            name="desc"
            placeholder="Enter Recipe description"
            onChange={e=>setUpdate(e.target.value)}
            >
            </FormControl>
          </FormGroup>
         
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={editRecipe}>Save</Button>
        <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal.Header>
    </Modal>
              </Accordion>
      )
    }
    
    export default Recipes
```

Can someone help me with the `editRecipes` function which is updating the records in the database? I don't know how to access all the three variables(`title`,`ingredients`,`desc`) in this function using the update `useState` hook I have defined above.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember rightly, `.split` converts a string into an array. Without knowing exactly what you are trying to split I expect you will need to render as an array. I suggest taking a look at this good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react). I have added a few examples of ReactJS map that you might find helpful:

```js
render() {
    return (<div>
    {this.state.people.map((person, index) => (
        <p key={index}>Hello, {person.name} from {person.country}!</p>
    ))}
    </div>);
}
```

```js
this.state.data.map(function(item, i){
  console.log('test');
  return <li key={i}>Test</li>
})
```

If you are using Cloud Firestore, then you might find these tutorials and guides helpful:

- [Getting started with Cloud Firestore and React Native](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage).
- [Create React Native Firebase CRUD App with Firestore](https://www.positronx.io/create-react-native-firebase-crud-app-with-firestore/).