# Rendering a box when submitting the data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following code in my React:

```
const [property, setProperty] = useState([]);
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ type: "", propertyName: "" });

const handleChange = (e, inputField) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [inputField]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (state.type !== "" && state.propertyName !== "") {
      const newObject = { type: state.type, propertyName: state.propertyName };
      property.push(newObject);
      console.log(property);
      setState({
        type: "",
        propertyName: "",
      });
    }
  };
```

And html:

```
          <div>
            <label htmlFor='properties' className='properties-label'>
              Properties
            </label>
            <div className='property-box'>
              <input
                type='text'
                id='type'
                value={state.type}
                placeholder='Type'
                className='type-element'
                required
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "type")}
              ></input>
              <input
                type='text'
                id='name'
                value={state.propertyName}
                className='type-element'
                placeholder='Name'
                required
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "propertyName")}
              ></input>
              <button
                className='buttonAccount'
                type='submit'
                onClick={handleSubmit}
              >
                Add Property
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

What I want is when I press the add Property button a new html tag will render on the page(a box or something like that containing the two fields that has been inputted). Can you help me find a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [print the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react) in your `property` array. For exmaple:

```js
{
  property.map((element) => (
    <div key={element.propertyName}>
      <span>
        {element.type}
      </span>
      <span>
        {element.propertyName}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Javascript array `map` method to map each item in your `property` state into an HTML element.

For example:

1. Make a function that returns the mapped `property` state into HTML elements.

```
const renderProperties = () => {
      return property.map((item, index) => (
           // `item` is a representation of each of your object in the property array
           // In this case, item contains { type: string, propertyName: string }
           <div key={index}> // React requires user to put a key in each of the mapped component
               <p>{item.propertyName}</p>
               <p>{item.type}</p>
           </div>
      ))
 }
```

2. Call this function inside the HTML part of your JSX.

```
              ...
              <button
                className='buttonAccount'
                type='submit'
                onClick={handleSubmit}
              >
                Add Property
              </button>
            </div>
            {renderProperties()} // <-- Here
          </div>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html