# Can't include code execution at jsx top level?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

For the following code, it will gives exception when include the line `{console.log('hello');}`

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const ages = [1, 2];
  return (
    <>
      {ages.map((age) => (
        {console.log('hello');} //include this code gives unexpected token
        <h1>{age}</h1>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit thirsty-beaver-5t6c6j]

What is the syntax rule that gives this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering an array.map() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react)

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing syntax of arrow functions. There is an implicit return pattern which helps use skip the `return` statement, but with that you cannot write statements inside your code. You have to write an expression to be returned.

Use the curly braces, along with return:

```
      {ages.map((age) => {
        console.log("hello");
        return <h1>{age}</h1>;
      })}
```

[Arrow functions details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-scott-rw4e30)

Answer (score 2):

You are returning directly from a map callback function. This should work:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const ages = [1, 2];
  return (
    <>
      {ages.map((age) => {
        console.log("hello");
        return <h1>{age}</h1>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-lamport-hps84d

Answer (score 1):

The returning value of a function in JSX has to be a React Node, so in order to call the function like that, you need to make it into a fragment, so that you do return a React Node.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const ages = [1, 2];
  return (
    <>
      {ages.map((age) => (
        <>
          {console.log('hello')}
          <h1>{age}</h1>
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```