# Reorder or create new array based on object indexes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I need to render the below object into subsequent tr/tds via JSX...

```
    {
  "0": [
    {
      "colIndex": 0,
      "data": {
        "richTextModule": "Data row 1 cell 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "colIndex": 0,
      "data": {
        "richTextModule": "Data row 2 cell 1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "colIndex": 1,
      "data": {
        "richTextModule": "Data row 1 cell 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "colIndex": 1,
      "data": {
        "richTextModule": "Data row 2 cell 2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "colIndex": 2,
      "data": {
        "richTextModule": "Data row 1 cell 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "colIndex": 2,
      "data": {
        "richTextModule": "Data row 2 cell 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "colIndex": 2,
      "data": {
        "richTextModule": "Data row 3 cell 3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried

```
Object.values(obj).map((column, index) => {
    return column.map((row, rowIndex) => {
        return obj[index][rowIndex].data.richTextModule;
    });
}
```

Expected output should be...

```
    <tr>
        <td>Data row 1 cell 1</td>
        <td>Data row 1 cell 2</td>
        <td>Data row 1 cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data row 2 cell 1</td>
        <td>Data row 2 cell 2</td>
        <td>Data row 2 cell 3</td>   
    </tr>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: FYI: You're not returning anything from your `Object.values().map()` call.

Comment: @ChrisG Surely abstracting the data re-ordering out of the component rendering is a valid way to go about it no? I know how to render tables in React.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Yes, you'll want to create a two dimensional array first. This has nothing to do with React btw (which is what confused me)

Comment: Yeah my mistake @ChrisG - ultimate goal is to render the resulting array into table in JSX but nothing to do with the data sorting I agree

Comment: Here's one way it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/0jh1Luad/

Answer (score 0):

Think what you're trying to do is:

```
<table>
{Object.values(obj).map((col, index) => <tr key={index}>{
      col.map((row, rowIndex) => <td key={rowIndex}>${obj[index][rowIndex].data.richTextModule}</td>)
    }</tr>
)}
</table>
```

or you could do:

```
<table>
  {Object.values(obj).map((col, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        {col.map((row, rowIndex) => {
          return <td key={rowIndex}>${obj[index][rowIndex].data.richTextModule}</td>
        })}
      </tr>
    )
  })}
</table>
```

You should return in a `map`, reference:

- [Rendering an array.map() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react)

You also should add a `key`, reference:

- [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: The array has to be restructured because the inner arrays contain the cells of a column, not a row

Comment: ah I thought his issue was he couldnt get it to work and his code was wrong